# jQuery 1.5.1 ajax JSON data is null on controller

Tags: jquery

My ajax call looking like that:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/GenerateExportReport",
        data: "{ 'fromDate': '2004-12-01', 'toDate': '2011-12-01', 'requestorId': = '1'}",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        },

        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown + " text:" + textStatus + "request " + XMLHttpRequest);
        }
    });
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GenerateExportReport(string data)
{
  . . .
}
```

The call is working but JSON data didn't come tho controller fore some reason, `string data` is NULL at every call.

I did try some fixes from this links

fix `jQuery.ajaxSetup()` from that link [JQuery 1.5 and new "Text JSON" datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955582/jquery-1-5-and-new-text-json-datatype) didn't help

fix contentType: `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`, from that link [Sending String Data to MVC Controller using jQuery $.ajax() and $.post()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843017/sending-string-data-to-mvc-controller-using-jquery-ajax-and-post)
didn't work either, when I am setting `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, I am getting error code 500 internal server error

Also as mentioned in one of the posts [jQuery 1.5.1 breaks all ajax() calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276790/jquery-1-5-1-breaks-all-ajax-calls) that it could be `jQuery validation plugin` so currently i did remove the reference to this script from my page at all.

Any thoughts?

P.S
string in data (`{ 'fromDate': '2004-12-01', 'toDate' ... }`) is only an example, I have very big JSON string which I need to pass to controller:

```
["ONE", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "TWO", "281", "5174", "70", "3406", "1405", "300", "4632", "1522", "16790", "TREE", "13", "174", "4", "119", "32", "18", "94", "45", "499", "FOUR", "28", "931", "17", "755", "414", "17", "1138", "353", "3653", "FIVE", "2", "30", "0", "12", "8", "0", "12", "3", "67", "SIX", "13", "250", "7", "173", "77", "18", "247", "49", "834", "9am", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "4", "SEVEN", "185", "2838", "45", "2100", "828", "314", "2324", "1223", "9857", "EIGHT", "173", "3662", "23", "1798", "612", "95", "2007", "445", "8815", "NINE", "308", "5277", "52", "3800", "1842", "154", "5548", "1910", "18891", "TEN", "17", "233", "3", "145", "69", "21", "199", "70", "757", "Total", "1020", "18572", "221", "12308", "5287", "937", "16202", "5621", "60168"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not being a value to a field called "data" in your output, you're just setting a string to the output. To get this to appear, change your data value to this:

```
data: { data: "{ 'fromDate': '2004-12-01', 'toDate': '2011-12-01', 'requestorId': = '1'}" },
```

This is awful though. I think you should do this instead:

```
data: { fromDate: '2004-12-01', toDate: '2011-12-01', requestorId: 1}
```

then

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GenerateExportReport(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, int requestorId)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC does not by default treat action arguments as JSON. If using ASP.NET MVC 3 you can try the JsonValueProviderFactory:

Put this code in Global.asax to register it:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

Alternatively use regular arguments:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Reports/GenerateExportReport",
    data: {fromDate: '2004-12-01', toDate: '2011-12-01', requestorId: 1}
    /* rest */
});

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GenerateExportReport(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, int requestorId)
{
   /* implementation */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please check whether the following code works for you:**

```
var param = {};
param.fromDate = '2004-12-01';
param.toDate = '2011-12-01';
param.requestorId = '1';

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/GenerateExportReport",
                data: param,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                },

                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown + " text:" + textStatus + "request " + XMLHttpRequest);
                }
            });
```

**Code in Controller**

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult GenerateExportReport()
    {
    //Code to get the data
    Request.Form["fromDate"]
    Request.Form["toDate"]
    Request.Form["requestorId"]
    }
```