# How to call ActionMethod from javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button that prompts user about his action(deleting smth). If user confirms, I want to execute `ActionMethod` with `postback`. How can i achieve that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764965/basic-ajax-example-with-asp-net-mvc/765974#765974 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843017/sending-string-data-to-mvc-controller-using-jquery-ajax-and-post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is simple, you can do it this way

**JS**

```
$('#id-of-your-button').click(function() {
    if(confirm('Are you sure'))
         document.location = '/controller/action/id_to_delete';
});
```

or with the postback

```
$('#id-of-your-button').click(function() {
  if(!confirm('Are you sure'))
       return false;
});
```

if your button is not submit button than you can do it this way

```
$('#id-of-your-button').click(function() {
      if(confirm('Are you sure'))
           $('#id-of-your-form').submit();
      return false;
    });
```

if you don't have anything (form and submit button)

```
$('#id-of-your-button').click(function(){
  $.ajax({ url: '/controller/action', 
    dataType: 'html', 
    data: { id_to_delete: $('#where_are_you_holding_your_value').val() },
    type: 'post', 
    success: function(data) {
       alert('your item is deleted');
    }
});
```

Comment: What if it is post method(and it obviously has to be be) ?

Comment: I have fixed code, look at it now, if your button is submit button of your form

Comment: What if i don't have submit button?